# Elgg Installation Synatx Error (Unexpected '[')

Tags: php, elgg

I am having trouble with my elgg installation for my website. Every time I load the "install.php" in the root directory, I keep getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in (Root)/engine/classes/Elgg/Di/ServiceProvider.php on line 194

Here is line 194 in that file:

```
$params = $c->config->get('cookies')['session'];
```

I have PHP version 5.3.13. Can anyone help?

Comment: Oops, accidentally pressed enter. Will fix (EDIT: Fixed)

Comment: Array dereferencing introduced in php5.4

Comment: @u_mulder Does that mean I have to contact my service provider in order to upgrade to that version?

Comment: Yes you would have to contact your provider and check if he can upgrade your php otherwise you can just use a temp variable

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can't be referenced directly from a return object in PHP below 5.4.
[[Documentation]](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102)

You can't do this:

```
$params = $c->config->get('cookies')['session'];
```

But you CAN do this:

```
$cookies = $c->config->get('cookies');
$params = $cookies['session'];
```

Or you can just upgrade your PHP installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because you don't have PHP version 5.4 or higher!

So change this:

```
$params = $c->config->get('cookies')['session'];
```

to this:

```
$params = $c->config->get('cookies');
$params = $params['session'];
```

For more information about array dereferencing  see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

And a quote from there:

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.